# How to get all uid of messages using "$ UID SEARCH ALL"?

Tags: c#, email, imap, tcpclient

I am trying to get all messages id from my email,but it doesn't work. I get this answer:

`$ BAD [CLIENTBUG] Unrecognised command\r\n\0\0\0\0`.

How do I get the correct response?

```
string uids1 = ReceiveResponse("$ SELECT INBOX\r\n");
string uids = ReceiveResponse("$ UID SEARCH ALL" + "\r\n");//query to server

private string ReceiveResponse(string command)
{
    _sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        if (command != "")
        {
            if (_tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                _dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                _ssl.Write(_dummy, 0, _dummy.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("TCP CONNECTION DISCONNECTED");
            }
        }
        _ssl.Flush();

        _buffer = new byte[2048];
        _tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 20000;

        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

        do
        {
            try
            {
                bytes = _ssl.Read(_buffer, 0, 2048);

                var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_buffer);

                _sb.Append(msg);
                Thread.Sleep(3);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        } while (_tcpClient.Available > 0);

        string text = _sb.ToString().Replace("\0", string.Empty);

        return _sb.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)//if we have some problem show message
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you logged in and `SELECT`ed a folder yet?  `UID` is only valid in the folder selected state.

Comment: @Max yes,i have

Comment: Please update your MVCE to include relevant code then; this code snippet is not sufficient on it's own!

Comment: You can get rid of the `\0`'s in your string by doing `var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (_buffer, 0, bytes);`

Comment: Your loop for reading the response is also incorrect - you can't rely on using `_tcpClient.Available > 0` because the data may arrive slower than your 3 millisecond timeout. I'd bet anything that you added that `Thread.Sleep()` there because you already ran into that problem. To do things correctly, you need to parse the response as you read it so that you know when the response is complete or if you are still waiting for more data. When you do it the right way, you won't need to check `_tcpClient.Available`.